# Regarding using date time in a string format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to figure out how to subtract a date time from today's date but it keeps coming back with a very large amount of days for whenever i enter an enroll date. Here is the code I have so far

```
    public string getTimeAsStudent(DateTime EnrolledDate)
    {
        return DateTime.Today.Subtract(EnrolledDate).ToString();

    }

    public string getTimeAsStudent()
    {
        return DateTime.Today.Subtract(oEnrolledDate).TotalDays.ToString();

    }
```

and here is what I have for the test app

```
 namespace StudentTestApp
   {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Student.StudentGrades myStudent = new Student.StudentGrades();

    private void getDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblDate.Text = myStudent.getTimeAsStudent().ToString();
    }
}
```

Helper variables

```
   public class StudentGrades
   {
    private string oStudentFirstName;
    private string oStudentMiddleName;
    private string oStudentLastName;
    private string oStudentID;
    private string oAddress;
    private string oEmail;
    private DateTime oEnrolledDate;
    private string oMajor;
    private string oPhone;
    private string oZip;
    private List<string> oCourseCompleted;
    private List<string> oCourseQtrYr;
    private List<double> oCourseGrade;
```

However it outputs like 736,000 days for no matter what date i put in, Can anyone help with this??

Comment: What is `oEnrolledDate`?

Comment: You are getting the `TotalHours` as per your code not `TotalDays`

Comment: Could you provide where you're defining 'oEnrolledDate'?

Comment: oEnrolledDate is a helper variable for my constructor, I have enrolledDate in there as well, I know i need to pass a textbox1.text to it as well but it doesn't like it at all and I can't parse from the date time into the string, that has to be done in the class part but I thought I did do that, but it still wasn't working. So I'm really confused

Comment: What did you expect? DateTime.Subtract( DateTime ) returns a TimeSpan

Comment: I am trying to get the DateTime to pass into a textbox.text with a date entereed like 05/26/2017 and then it will take that date (which is the enrolled date) and convert it to the total days and put the total days into a label.Text

Comment: But where did you assign that DateTime from the TextBox to myStudent.oEnrolledDate? I did not see any line of code with that. Use the debugger to see what values are passed to the method

Comment: I tryied to put enrolleddate to textbox.text but it wont let me call the method with that like i tried...lblDate.Text =  myStudent.getTimeAsStudent().EnrolledDate(textBox4.Text);

Comment: @Jason rewrite this as a commandline app (as it contains much less code). Then make the code as short as you can. Post the shortest possible code that shows the problem you are facing.

Comment: @Jason Did you ever assign a value to myStudent.oEnrolledDate? If not the result is not surprising. And myStudent.getTimeAsStudent().EnrolledDate(textBox4.Text); did not make sense at all.

Comment: I got it all working now, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's types of Subtract methods

How To Get Subtract of two DateTime To Years

```
public static string getTimeAsYear(DateTime oEnrolledDate)
{
        return (Math.Abs(oEnrolledDate.Year - DateTime.Today.Year)).ToString();
}
```

How To Get Subtract of two DateTime To Month

```
public static string getTimeAsMonth(DateTime oEnrolledDate)
{
        return ((Math.Abs(oEnrolledDate.Year - DateTime.Today.Year)) * 12).ToString();
}
```

And Result

`DateTime D = new DateTime(1995,01,17);
 Console.WriteLine(getTimeAsStudent(D));
 Console.WriteLine(getTimeAsYear(D));
 Console.WriteLine(getTimeAsMonth(D));`

[image]